# iOS MKMapView with location search on bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am attempting to build an iOS 5 application with a map populated with points around a user's location. The map is nested in a navigation controller with a search bar along the bottom. The search bar is connected to a UITableView that is below the search bar (For the search results). All of these three views are within a UIScrollView.

The hierarchy is as follows:

- Navigation Controller

  - UI View

    - Scroll View (contains the following 3)

      - Map View
      - Search Bar
      - Table View

I apologize for not being able to post images, but I can direct you to another app that is doing almost the exact same thing, which is [Dark Sky](http://darkskyapp.com).

Here's what I would like to happen: When the user taps in the search bar, the view scrolls up, revealing the table view with the results (while also shifting to show the cancel button). After searching and finding something or canceling, the view will slide back down to reveal the map again (with the search bar at the bottom). This is done beautifully with [Dark Sky](http://darkskyapp.com).

I have seen other questions that sort of address my problem, however, none of them fully illustrate a solution. Any best practices on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want a `UIScrollView` here.  Only use that when you want the user to control the scrolling.

You may be able to use the existing [UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) functionality, as demonstrated in the [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html) example.  Note that, while the background view in that example is a `UITableView`, that is *not* the sample table used to display search results.  You can see this if you change the style of the background table.  So, you can also use an `MKMapView` as the background, and still have a table of search results.

If the transition behavior provided by UISearchDisplayController doesn't suit, you will need to create and animate the search results table yourself.  In your interface design, position the search results table out of sight below the screen.  When the user searches, use [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3a) to move the table into its correct place.  (Just make the table frame take the same value as the map frame.)

If you allow rotation to different device orientations, you may need to update the table position when rotation happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the scrollView's content offset manually when the user finish entering the search text?

Offset scrollview by negative height of mapview.

```
myScrollView.contentOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -heightOfMapView);
```

Or use CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation

```
myScrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -heightOfMap);
```

Then when you want the map back, use reset the transformation translation:

```
myScrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: Every TableView has a property tableHeaderview:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableHeaderView
```

Put the `searchBar` and the `mapView` inside the `tableHeaderView`. So you use the `tableHeaderView` as a container view and scroll the `tableView` accordingly so it just shows the `tableHeaderView`.